# Converting Varchar Value to Integer/Decimal Value in SQL Server

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

How to convert the value of records in a table with data type `varchar` to `integer` or `decimal` so I can get the sum of the value. I use `SQL Server 2005`.

Say that I have table structure like this:

```
ID int
Stuff varchar
```

and the records

```
ID = 1, Stuff = 32.43
ID = 2, Stuff = 43.33
ID = 3, Stuff = 23.22
```

Now I want to get the total of column Stuff:

```
SELECT SUM(convert(decimal(4,2), Stuff)) as result FROM table
```

But it doesn't work. Please need help!

Comment: Are you getting any error? Try to run without the aggregation first

Comment: Still not work. Msg 102, 
error: Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Table structure...very basic:

```
create table tabla(ID int, Stuff varchar (50));

insert into tabla values(1, '32.43');
insert into tabla values(2, '43.33');
insert into tabla values(3, '23.22');
```

Query:

```
SELECT SUM(cast(Stuff as decimal(4,2))) as result FROM tabla
```

Or, try this:

```
SELECT SUM(cast(isnull(Stuff,0) as decimal(12,2))) as result FROM tabla
```

Working on SQLServer 2008

Comment: I believe the OP has more than those 3 records

Comment: I made the test based on the sample data proposed by the user

Comment: Still not work in sql server 2005: "Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric."

Comment: Are you having some columns with stuff = null??

Answer (score 2):

You are getting arithmetic overflow. this means you are trying to make a conversion impossible to be made. This error is thrown when you try to make a conversion and the destiny data type is not enough to convert the origin data. For example:

If you try to convert 100.52 to decimal(4,2) you will get this error. The number 100.52 requires 5 positions and 2 of them are decimal.

Try to change the decimal precision to something like 16,2 or higher. Try with few records first then use it to all your select.

Answer (score 1):

The reason could be that the summation exceeded the required number of digits - 4. If you increase the size of the decimal to `decimal(10,2)`, it should work

```
 SELECT SUM(convert(decimal(10,2), Stuff)) as result FROM table
```

OR

```
 SELECT SUM(CAST(Stuff AS decimal(6,2))) as result FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it without casting such as:

```
select sum(`stuff`) as mySum from test;
```

Or cast it to decimal:

```
select sum(cast(`stuff` as decimal(4,2))) as mySum from test;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5edf8/1)

**EDIT**

For SQL Server, you can use:

```
select sum(cast(stuff as decimal(5,2))) as mySum from test;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6e7cf/6)

Comment: First Option generates error: Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator.
Second Option generates error: Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: My apologies, you tagged as `mysql` so that's what I did the test in.

Comment: @PhilipsTel Updated the SQL fiddle to MS SQL Server with example.